# Imitating the other gender

Tags: vocabulary

What adjective would describe best a person who is neither Trans nor intersex, but that person only imitates the other gender? That person wears women's clothes such as, if that is a man, or wears men's clothes, if that is a woman.

> feminine-man/ masculine-woman
>
> woman-like man/ man-like woman

or what? The first sounds really weird, to me at least.

Comment: Also, your choice of "feminine man" or "masculine woman" might be simplest, aside from the fact that defining "feminine" and "masculine" is the topic of entire fields of study, with much sharp disagreement.

Comment: Did you ask them how they would like to be described?

Comment: No. The impression I am getting  from your comment is that we must ensure how they want to be described, we must what their preference is.

Comment: In the region, I belong to Trans  like to use female pronouns for themselves. This que of mine is not about Trans, it's about those who are the gender they are bilogically, but just imitate the other gender.

Comment: IMSop's words suggestions look  ok.

Answer (score 3):

This can be a delicate topic. Be sure you know exactly what your words mean before using them. As Andy Bonner points out, it is often better to describe someone's behavior rather than immediately assigning them a label *as a person* based on that behavior. However, there are some terms that might be used:

In general, someone who wears the "other" type of clothes is engaging in [**cross-dressing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-dressing) and can be called a **cross-dresser**. You may hear the word [**transvestite**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transvestism) as well (which is Latin for, literally, "cross-dressed") but it has become dated and moderately offensive in modern usage.

Someone who does this as a *performance art* is engaging in [**drag**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(clothing)) and can be called a [**drag queen**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_queen) (if dressing as a woman) or [**drag king**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_king) (if dressing as a man).

A woman, especially a girl or young woman, who engages in stereotypical "boy's play" can be called a [**tomboy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomboy). This term is also dated but not offensive, unless the context makes it offensive. Wikipedia points to [**sissy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sissy) as the inverse term for men, but correctly notes that it is *much* more pejorative  than "tomboy."

In the LGBTQ community there are the specific terms [**twink**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twink_(gay_slang)) (a young, slim, often effeminate gay man) and [**butch**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butch_and_femme) (a masculine lesbian). They are not inherently offensive when used by LGBTQ people themselves, but because they describe someone's personal identity and gender expression they must be used very carefully.

Then there are insults, such as **girly boy** or **lady boy**, which mock someone for their traits or behavior. These are more often directed at men who dress as women rather than the other way around.

Comment: "Lady boy" would make me think of [Asian trans women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathoey) rather than a generally lady-like man.

Comment: Sometimes, some of these 'definitions' depend on the age of the person. I know two older men [60's] who would slap you for calling them a cross-dresser & absolutely insist on, to them, their 'correct' term, transvestite. [Incidentally, they don't know each other; one of them is gay with a husband, the other is straight with a wife & children, so there's no commonality except the similarity in their ages] I'm certain much of this is a personal choice & I would hesitate to label anyone without first asking them if they have a preference.

Answer (score 1):

Words about identity and behavior need to be very specialized. You're asking for a word describing the whole person (identity), but it might be better to describe the behavior. Wearing the clothes of the other gender is [transvestism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transvestism) (adjective form: *transvestite*). It is distinct from sexual or gender identity, and is applicable to any gender (though, in modern western society, "women's clothing" has long incorporated many aspects of what was previously limited to men's clothing, like trousers, so the distinction is less distinct).

Answer (score 1):

As randomhead's great answer says: **this is a delicate topic, so be very careful**.

"Feminine" and "masculine" can certainly be used to describe someone. Note that no hyphen is used between an ordinary adjective and a noun, so it would be "feminine man", not "feminine-man".

Other relevant adjectives:

- [effeminate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effeminate) for a man acting in ways considered typical of a woman, or not living up to the expectations of "manliness"
- [manly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manly) and [womanly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/womanly) are usually used to denote someone who is particularly typical of their own gender, but can be used the other way around: "a manly woman" or "a womanly man"
- [butch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/butch) broadly means "strong", but is often used for a particularly masculine woman, usually a lesbian